# Why are vector and layer masks commonly used in Photoshop web design templates?

Tags: css, vector, photoshop, layer

Do they aid the PSD to XHTML and CSS conversion process?  If so, how?  Is there some other advantage these features provide in the context of Web design?

Comment: Um, don't know that it helps "conversion" to XHTML, but it helps when creating complex graphics...? I'm confused about the question.

Comment: Oh i c, both layer and vector masks are just used for the graphic design of the psd file?

Comment: They don't have anything to do with CSS layers, or in fact the "final XHTML/CSS output", if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ya, thats basically what I was looking for, if vector and layer masks have any control or role in the PSD to xhtml and CSS conversion process.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector graphics is the use of geometrical primitives such as points, lines, curves, and shapes or polygon(s), which are all based on mathematical equations, to represent images in computer graphics.
its just related to designing a web layout with photoshop,and psd files contains editable data for layout only...there is no link between css and xhtml with photoshop,it stand alone for creating web layout....

Answer (score 0):

The way that production goes: graphic designer makes a web design in photoshop, cuts it in proper pieces, and sends to programmers. They take this pieces and make a new website, using html/xhtml/css/xslt/JS/ or whatever technology they need. 
Ergo: photoshop has nothing to do with html/css sites building.